# I was trying to convert my code from Python to JS, because I want to use HTML with my JavaScript c. My question is, how do I convert this code to java

Tags: python

```
import random
import os
import collections
from collections import OrderedDict
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import pylab
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

h1 = input("Enter subsequent: ")

Test = []
for n in range(1):

    # Function to convert

    def listToString(s):

        # initialize an empty string
        str1 = ""
        # traverse in the string
        for ele in s:
            str1 += ele
        # return string
        return str1

    # Driver code
    S = listToString(h2)

    def count_kmers(sequence, k):
        d = collections.defaultdict(int)
        for i in range(len(S) - (k - 1)):
            d[sequence[i : i + k]] += 1

        return d

    def probabilities(kmer_count, k):
        probabilities = collections.defaultdict(float)
        N = len(S)
        for key, value in kmer_count.items():
            probabilities[key] = float(value) / (N - k + 1)
        return probabilities

    def chaos_game_representation(probabilities, k):
        array_size = int(math.sqrt(4 ** k))
        chaos = []
        for i in range(array_size):
            chaos.append([0] * array_size)
        maxx = array_size
        maxy = array_size
        posx = 1
        posy = 1
        for key, value in probabilities.items():
            for char in key:
                if char == "T":
                    posx += maxx // 2
                elif char == "C":
                    posy += maxy // 2
                elif char == "G":
                    posx += maxx // 2
                    posy += maxy // 2
                maxx = maxx // 2
                maxy //= 2
            chaos[posy - 1][posx - 1] = value
            maxx = array_size
            maxy = array_size
            posx = 1
            posy = 1

        return chaos

    p = count_kmers(S, 5)

    F = probabilities(p, 5)

    chaos_k3 = chaos_game_representation(F, 5)

    pylab.title("Chaos game representation for 3-mers")
    pylab.imshow(chaos_k3, interpolation="nearest", cmap=cm.gray_r)

    def flatten_list(_2d_list):
        flat_list = []
        # Iterate through the outer list
        for element in _2d_list:
            if type(element) is list:
                # If the element is of type list, iterate through the sublist
                for item in element:
                    flat_list.append(item)
            else:
                flat_list.append(element)
        return flat_list

    Test.append(flatten_list(chaos_k3))
print(Test)


import csv
import cv2

file = open("test.csv", "w+", newline="")


# writing the data into the file

with file:

    write = csv.writer(file)

    write.writerows(Test)
test_u = pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=None)
test_u

X_train = (test_u.iloc[:1, :].values).astype("float32")

F11 = X_train.reshape(test_u.shape[0], 32, 32, 1)
F11.shape
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to convert this whole to JS (!= java)?
there are some interesting web framework to use python to interact with HTML elements and import your function in python native language.

I'd suggest digging into Flask. This simple snippet allows you to render an html page (main.html) where you can *return* Python functions or even variables to use in the code. This is also more efficient since allows you to segregate BE and FE functions. You can even add further interaction with JS scripts if you need.
Then you can also easily hosts it online with PythonAnywhere or Heroku.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/', methods = ["GET"])
def input_page():
    return render_template("main.html")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(use_reloader=False)
```

(I am sorry, this should be more appropriate as a comment, but I have not enough reputation. However I didn't want to miss a chance to help :))

Comment: I can't because l need to use this code inside js where I have model and I have to use tfjs. so I have to convert this code to java script.